# Ошибка "The indentation error " в Python

Tags: python

Пожалуйста, помогите, я написал свою пробную программу по примеру системы банкомата и столкнулся с ошибкой (указанной выше) проверял код ничего не нашёл. ( я только начинающий по этому мой код может быть ужасен)

```
Print (" Баланс = 29.00 руб ")
c = Float(29.00)
Deystvie = imput(" Вывести, Положить, Оставить")
a = Float(input(" Введите сумму:"))

if Daystvie == "Вывести":
    b = c - a
    print (" Остаток:" + str(b))
elif Daystvie =="Положить":
x = Float(inpute(" Введите сумму:"))
    k = c + x
    print (" Остаток:" + str(k))
elif Daystvie ==" Оставить":
    print (" Остаток:" + str(a))
```

P.s: заранее спасибо за то что вы обратили внимание на мой вопрос.

Comment: После elif должен быть отступ для начала нового блока, а у вас отступа нет

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Удачи вам и доброй ночи.

Comment: Если читать ошибку полностью, то можно даже увидеть строку, в которой она произошла. И по поводу следующих ошибок: функции пишутся с маленькой буквы, Deystvie и Daystvie - разные слова, а input написано три раза и все три раза по-разному 

Answer (score 3):

- Во-первых, все функции и переменные следует писать с маленькой буквы.
- Во-вторых, `Deystvie` и `Daystvie` - не одно и то же. Всегда внимательно проверяйте имена переменных.
- В третьих, `input` пишется только так и никак иначе. У Вас же в **`3`**-х случаях это слово написано по разному.
- А так же, после `elif peremennaya == '':` перед текстом обязательно должен быть отступ.

Ну а сама ошибка возникла из-за того, что после `elif peremennaya == '':` обязательно должны находиться **4** пробела.